# How to pack chromedriver.exe on Mac

Tags: selenium, electron, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Selenium on Electron app and am using the following modules:

```
"chromedriver": "^78.0.1",
"selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.4",
"electron-builder": "^21.2.0",
```

I built my app on a Mac and Selenium is working fine. However, when I run Electron Selenium app on Widows it can't find `chromedriver`.

`react-electron/node_modules/chromedriver` is below.

[image]

Of course it doesn't have `chromedriver.exe`, so I put `chromedriver.exe` into `chromedriver/bin`. Then I built it again but the built app doesn't include `chromedriver.exe`. How can I pack `chromedriver.exe` into the built app?

I applicate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I put chromedriver.exe into `node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver`.

I can check it was copied in 
`win-unpacked/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe`

When the app run, chromedriver can fined in `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MyApp\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\chromedriver\lib\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe`

I can get the driver path like this.

```
const chromedriver = require('chromedriver');

async getDriverPath() {
    let driverPath:string = this.chromedriver.path;
    driverPath = await driverPath.replace('app.asar','app.asar.unpacked');
    log.info("this.driverPath " + driverPath);
    return driverPath;
}
```

And also, I set driver path like this.

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const {Builder} = webdriver;
let my_driver;

async startChrome() {
        const driverPath = await this.getDriverPath();
        const service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(driverPath).build();
        chrome.setDefaultService(service);
        my_driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    }
```

I hope this will help someone.